# Create a pcl::PointCloud::Ptr from a pcl::PointCloud

Tags: c++, pointers, point-cloud-library

I would like to know if this is possible. I have a function:

```
 pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> createPointCloud(std::Vector<Nodes> input)
```

which returns a point cloud. I would like to know if it is possible to take this point cloud, and make a pointer to a copy of it. pcl makes pointers to clouds like this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudPTR(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>)
```

I have tried doing this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudPTR(createPointCloud(nodeList))
```

This results in a pretty obvious error ie. createPointCloud doesnt return a pointer to a cloud.

I have also tried this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudPTR = &createPointCloud(nodeList)
```

and this:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudPTR(&createPointCloud(nodeList))
```

And this results in the compile error: "taking address of temporary"

Is the only option to have the function return a pointer type or is there a way to do what i am asking?

EDIT:

Both of the below answers are correct, I have awarded Jonathon the correct tick as he got in first this time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is old and probably of no more use to OP, but other users might stumble upon it. I would suggest doing it as follows:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloudPTR(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
*cloudPTR = createPointCloud(nodeList);
```

The reason Jonathon's answer is dangerous is that Pointcloud::Ptr is a typedef for a boost::shared_ptr which implies ownership of the object pointed to. In his answer, however, the object is actually a local variable meaning that it might go out of scope while there are still references to it and that shared_ptr will eventually call delete on it, which is undefined behavior.

Using make_shared() on the other hand deep copies the cloud. The program will work correctly, but if you didn't need the extra copy, it is far from optimal.

Comment: Which pcl header file needs to be included for this one?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, use the [makeShared()](http://docs.pointclouds.org/trunk/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#ab9db5c9a9d98d6256c510d436693ab5f) method.

Comment: he's not using std::shared_ptr. he's using a library specific RAII ptr class. std::make_shared() will not work with it.

Comment: @johnathon  Where did I mention std:: anything?  Follow the link.

Comment: This might work as well, I have used @jonathon's answer though.

Comment: Ptr pcl::PointCloud< PointT >::makeShared is not make_shared(), ergo the reference to the std lib.

Comment: @Ben, if you look at the code, it's just a convenience wrapper for `Ptr (new PointCloud<PointT> (*this))`

Comment: I have tried using this method and it works a treat, @jonathon, you should remove your down vote. Both methods work.

Comment: @ergosys appologuise for the down vote, it's been removed. Sorry, make_shared() which is what you had is straight out of the std lib, easy to get confused if your accustom to using it in code as much as i am though.

Comment: @johnathon, OK, we can be friends now. ;-)

Comment: Very understandable @jonathon, thanks for both your input, they are both equally correct answers, who am i supposed to give the tick to?